# Change the timestamp value to date with ScriptTransformRecord

Tags: python, json, groovy, etl, apache-nifi

I'm trying to transform my data in a JSON from timestamp to date, using python ScriptTransformRecord process in apache nifi, how can i do this?

```
{
  "impressions_history_posts_seen" : [ {
    "string_map_data" : {
      "type_interaction" : "posts_viewed",
      "Author" : {
        "value" : "michis_chilean"
      },
      "Time" : {
        "timestamp" : 1705789168
      }
    }
  }, {
    "string_map_data" : {
      "type_interaction" : "posts_viewed",
      "Author" : {
        "value" : "karimee._____"
      },
      "Time" : {
        "timestamp" : 1705789185
      }
    }
  },
```

I have some JSONs files similar to this one, I want to change the timestamp value, I have tried many codes and many solutions but i always get error, I'm using apache nifi 1.25

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UpdateRecord for this, check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#format

Comment: Yes, I have try this before but I don understand why is not working 
I am using 
Record Reader: JsonTreeReader
Record Writter: JsonRecordSetWritter
Property: I tried with /timestamp /Time/timestamp */Time/timestamp
Value: format( toDate(/Time/timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss’Z'"), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

but i still getting the same output with the timestamp 
what am i doing wrong?